# Capture AVPlayer movie frames in realtime

Tags: iphone, frame, capture, movie, avplayer

Now I want to capture the frames of the movie playing with AVPlayer in realtime. I refernced  http://codethink.no-ip.org/wordpress/archives/673#comment-8146 and

```
m_playerSlow = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
m_playerSlow.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;

m_view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, m_viewCapture.frame.size.width, m_viewCapture.frame.size.height)];

AVPlayerLayer * _avPlayerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:m_playerSlow];
_avPlayerLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, m_view.frame.size.width, m_view.frame.size.height); 
[m_view.layer addSublayer:_avPlayerLayer];

[/*self.view*/m_viewCapture addSubview:m_view];

[playerItem release];

// add Draw View
m_viewDraw = [[DrawView alloc] initWithFrame:m_view.frame];
m_viewDraw.m_parent = self;
m_viewDraw.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
m_viewDraw.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

[m_viewCapture addSubview:m_viewDraw];
```

m_plyerSlow is AVPlayer, m_viewDraw is UIView to draw some shapes, and the m_viewCapture is the ScreenCaptureView.

When recording, I can record the shapes of m_viewDraw, but nothing with the m_playerSlow(AVPlayer).

What can I do?
Please help me.